# Backbone collection.add is not working

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a pretty basic setup like this:

```
var MusicModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var PlaylistCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: MusicModel,
    events: {'add':'add'},
    add: function(mdl){
        //This is working perfectly fine even output of model
        console.log(mdl);
    }
});

var playlistCollection = new PlaylistCollection();
playlistCollection.add(new Music(data));
```

The model is not actually added to the collection. If I try to use Chrome console and enter `playlistCollection.length` it will output 0 and `playlistCollection.models` will output `[]`.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Collections in Backbone already have an [add method](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-add). By writing your own, you mask the base method and prevent the the normal behavior: inserting a model into the collection. Rename your method to something else or call the base method to solve your problem:

```
var PlaylistCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: MusicModel,

    add: function(model, opts){
        Backbone.Collection.prototype.add.call(this, model, opts);
        console.log(model);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/WPrTu/

Comment: I don't know how could I miss something like this. Will accept in five minutes.

Comment: @user1188570 In those cases, I blame enthusiasm :)